# How to register spring beans in the @RefreshScope in a functional way?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've got a number of my own custom "starter" projects. I'm working on migrating to Spring Boot 2.0, Framework 5.0, and functional bean definition in these and elsewhere.

In the "starter" projects, the pattern I'm following for functional bean definition is using the `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer`.

Example config class trying to register a bean in the 'refresh' scope.

```
package my.package;

public class MyConfiguration implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
        context.registerBean(MyConfiguration.class);
        context.registerBean("myBean",
            MyBean.class,
            () -> new MyBeanImpl(context.getBean(MyBeanDependency.class)),
            bd -> bd.setScope("refresh"),
            bd -> bd.setLazyInit(true));
    }
}
```

Then, list this `MyConfiguration` in the `META-INF/spring.factories` file as such.

```
# context init
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
my.package.MyConfiguration
```

When I try to run an application with this starter on the classpath, I see exceptions on startup indicating there is no refresh scope.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'
```

My guess is this must be an issue of ordering. Meaning at the time my bean is being created, the `RefreshScope` bean hasn't been created yet? The `org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration` is what declares the `RefreshScope` bean.

Is there a good or suggested way to functionally register spring beans that need to be in the `@RefreshScope`?

Comment: Interesting question Jeff. A pity noone answered, and a pity I have no clue too

Answer (score 0):

This might help -  I marked a controller as RefreshScope but I was getting this error -

> DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'refresh'

Below mentioned snippet resolved this error.

```
    @DependsOn("refreshScope")
    public CustomScopeConfigurer servletCustomScopeConfigurer(RefreshScope refreshScope) {
        CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
        customScopeConfigurer.addScope("refresh", refreshScope);
        return customScopeConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public RefreshScope refreshScope(){
        return new RefreshScope();
    }
```

Ref:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1116